# Custom View Set Invisible and Visible is clearing the Plot of canvas

Tags: android, android-canvas, android-view, android-custom-view

I have a custom View . And am Drawing Line.

```
    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) 
       {

          super.onDraw(canvas); 

         canvas.DrawLine(0, 0, 700, 200, Green);
  }
```

And on the button Click , I am making this View  visible and Invisible. But when I am making it  Visible  again , the line is not visible. I do not want to redraw again. I want to retain the previous plot.  Any help please . I will be very thankful

```
         button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(bCheck)
            { 
            myView.setVisible(View.INVISIBLE);
             bcheck = false
             }else
             {
         myView.setVisible(View.VISIBLE);
               }

        }
    });
```

please help me ?

Comment: Sorry my mistake..I have edited the question.

Comment: Any one please help me on this